# How to embed an audio file in Word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word

Is there a way to embed an audio clip into Word? I have a poem typed up in Word and I have the audio of the poem being read; is Word capable of saving an audio file with the accompanying text?  Can I play the file in Word while looking at the text?

Win 7 64-bit.
Word 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can embed an audio file into MS Word.

1. Go to **Insert Tab** and click **Object** under **Text** group.
   [image]
2. After clicking Object, a dialog box will open. Go to **Create from File Tab** in the dialog box.
3. Then select an audio you want to embed by clicking **Browse** button and also check **Link to File** and **Display as Icon** checkboxes. In the end, click **OK** button to save the changes.
   [image]
4. Now you can see the Audio Icon in your Word 2010 document. In order to open that audio, just double click on the icon.
   [image]