# How can I embed an audio in Word document so that when I click or tap a word or line the embedded audio is played

Tags: microsoft-word, audio, embedding

No this question is not just about embedding the audio as outlined in related question ["How to embed an audio file in Word 2010?"](https://superuser.com/questions/371887/how-to-embed-an-audio-file-in-word-2010), but beyond that.

I need to give pronunciation guide on few complicated words of a paragraph. I have an audio file (a single MP3 file) that reads the complete paragraph as per my need.  I want to allow learners to tap or click those complicated words there by they can hear the audio of that word from the embedded MP3 file.  Usually, an application that is capable of doing this will allow to embed an audio and hyperlink the complicated words to this audio and also provide some extra meta data to specify start and stop duration in the audio.

If such way of specifying the start and stop position is not possible, at least I can still live with chopping my audio file into several files; embed them and hyperlink each and every word. Though this is bit tedious, I can still use this work around if I can embed and hyperlink each text.

I have to use Microsoft Word (DOCX any version) and not PowerPoint or other applications. Any suggestions are most welcome and thanks for your time.

Comment: Each sound byte must be played in full like the ones in Wikipedia.   https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pronunciation#English

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, similar features are available in Word 2007, and have been removed for security reasons.

Now we seem to have no other way to fulfill this requirement.

I can only suggest that you add a hyperlinked audio file near each text that needs to be read.